# Transactions for Smart Contract

Tags: transactions

What is the best way to get the list of all transactions which have happened for my smart-contract in a private setup?

Comment: Check this http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3478/259

Answer (score 1):

Set up an event that is fired when your smart contract function gets executed.

Using The DAO [code](http://etherscan.io/address/0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413#code) for example, you firstly define an event:

```
event Voted(uint indexed proposalID, bool position, address indexed voter);
```

When your transaction is executing a function, log the event using the following type of statement:

```
Voted(_proposalID, _supportsProposal, msg.sender);
```

You can then pick up the events using the following type of statement:

```
> var theDAOABI = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"proposals","outputs":[{"name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"name":"amount","type":"uint256"},{"name":"description","type":"string"},{"name":"votingDeadline","type":"uint256"},{"name":"open","type":"bool"},{"name":"proposalPassed","type":"bool"},{"name":"proposalHash","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"proposalDeposit","type":"uint256"},{"name":"newCurator","type":"bool"},{"name":"yea","type":"uint256"},{"name":"nay","type":"uint256"},{"name":"creator","type":"address"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"minTokensToCreate","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"rewardAccount","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"daoCreator","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"divisor","outputs":[{"name":"divisor","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"extraBalance","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_proposalID","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_transactionData","type":"bytes"}],"name":"executeProposal","outputs":[{"name":"_success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"unblockMe","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalRewardToken","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"actualBalance","outputs":[{"name":"_actualBalance","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"closingTime","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"allowedRecipients","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferWithoutReward","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"refund","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_recipient","type":"address"},{"name":"_amount","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_description","type":"string"},{"name":"_transactionData","type":"bytes"},{"name":"_debatingPeriod","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_newCurator","type":"bool"}],"name":"newProposal","outputs":[{"name":"_proposalID","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"DAOpaidOut","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"minQuorumDivisor","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_newContract","type":"address"}],"name":"newContract","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"balance","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_recipient","type":"address"},{"name":"_allowed","type":"bool"}],"name":"changeAllowedRecipients","outputs":[{"name":"_success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"halveMinQuorum","outputs":[{"name":"_success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"paidOut","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_proposalID","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_newCurator","type":"address"}],"name":"splitDAO","outputs":[{"name":"_success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"DAOrewardAccount","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"proposalDeposit","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"numberOfProposals","outputs":[{"name":"_numberOfProposals","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"lastTimeMinQuorumMet","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_toMembers","type":"bool"}],"name":"retrieveDAOReward","outputs":[{"name":"_success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"receiveEther","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"isFueled","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_tokenHolder","type":"address"}],"name":"createTokenProxy","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_proposalID","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getNewDAOAddress","outputs":[{"name":"_newDAO","type":"address"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_proposalID","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_supportsProposal","type":"bool"}],"name":"vote","outputs":[{"name":"_voteID","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"getMyReward","outputs":[{"name":"_success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"rewardToken","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFromWithoutReward","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"name":"_spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"remaining","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_proposalDeposit","type":"uint256"}],"name":"changeProposalDeposit","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"blocked","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"curator","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_proposalID","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_recipient","type":"address"},{"name":"_amount","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_transactionData","type":"bytes"}],"name":"checkProposalCode","outputs":[{"name":"_codeChecksOut","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"privateCreation","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"_curator","type":"address"},{"name":"_daoCreator","type":"address"},{"name":"_proposalDeposit","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_minTokensToCreate","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_closingTime","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_privateCreation","type":"address"}],"type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"_amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"_amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"FuelingToDate","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"CreatedToken","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Refund","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"proposalID","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"amount","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"newCurator","type":"bool"},{"indexed":false,"name":"description","type":"string"}],"name":"ProposalAdded","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"proposalID","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"position","type":"bool"},{"indexed":true,"name":"voter","type":"address"}],"name":"Voted","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"proposalID","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"result","type":"bool"},{"indexed":false,"name":"quorum","type":"uint256"}],"name":"ProposalTallied","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_newCurator","type":"address"}],"name":"NewCurator","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_recipient","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"_allowed","type":"bool"}],"name":"AllowedRecipientChanged","type":"event"}];
undefined
> var theDAOAddress = "0xBB9bc244D798123fDe783fCc1C72d3Bb8C189413";
undefined
> var theDAO = web3.eth.contract(theDAOABI).at(theDAOAddress);
undefined
> var theDAOVotedEvent = theDAO.Voted({}, {fromBlock: 1614771, toBlock: 'latest'});
undefined
> theDAOVotedEvent.watch(function(error, result){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
});
{
  callbacks: [function(error, result)],
  filterId: "0x5d0947e08a4e08102302bf0ca3352c91",
  ...
}
...
{"address":"0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413","args":{"position":true,"proposalID":"15","voter":"0xebbf5d7d649aedde2c27a8b850a2a3862595eb53"},"blockHash":"0x3d0e8b47fbb03727c72585fbe2fd5f25c69c03f2b832753567c2309f1ecb3b2a","blockNumber":1614808,"event":"Voted","logIndex":0,"transactionHash":"0x0060654808a2dee9710fa01e26adb46e77df03c17e453e8fddc8749269ffad92","transactionIndex":1}
{"address":"0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413","args":{"position":false,"proposalID":"11","voter":"0xebbf5d7d649aedde2c27a8b850a2a3862595eb53"},"blockHash":"0x607d940ebbbb17e6d5c3c8a871cd4783b271ddf71f4aeb83dbcdcaf8ce2154d9","blockNumber":1614812,"event":"Voted","logIndex":1,"transactionHash":"0x6b5cab6f7987d7283fdde051c76ace98c9f080bda6dbdf720689fc0c3958005b","transactionIndex":6}
...
```

See [How do I retrieve the Voted events from The DAO](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4452/how-do-i-retrieve-the-voted-events-from-the-dao) for the full reference.