# How do I retrieve the event data related to the creation and transfer of The DAO tokens?

Tags: the-dao, events, calldata

How do I retrieve the data related to the creation and transfer of The DAO tokens?

This data will be useful to trace the movements in The DAO balances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following are the scripts to retrieve the CreatedToken and Transfer events.

The complete data for the CreatedToken events can be found at [CreatedTokenEvents.txt](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bokkypoobah/TheDAOData/master/CreatedTokenEvents.txt). These are from blocks 1429038 to 
1599205. In the data, the sum of the amount column adds up to 1,172,775,159.1981 .

The incomplete data for the Transfer events can be found at [TransferEvents.txt](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bokkypoobah/TheDAOData/master/TransferEvents.txt). These are from blocks 1599207 to 1773290 and are continuing as transfers are still occurring.

There is a script to retrieve the Voted events in [How do I retrieve the Voted events from The DAO](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4452/how-do-i-retrieve-the-voted-events-from-the-dao).

### Script To Retrieve CreatedToken Events

```
#!/bin/sh

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Retrieve The DAO CreatedToken events. These events are from block 1429038 to 
# 1599205 when the creation phase ended.
#
# Usage:
#   1. Download this script to getTheDAOCreatedTokenEvents .
#   2. `chmod 700 getTheDAOCreatedTokenEvents`
#   3. Run `geth console` in a window.
#   4. Then run this script `./getTheDAOCreatedTokenEvents` in a separate window.
#
# Enjoy. (c) BokkyPooBah 2016. The MIT licence.
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

geth attach << EOF 
var theDAOABIFragment = [{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"CreatedToken","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"_amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"}];
var theDAOAddress = "0xBB9bc244D798123fDe783fCc1C72d3Bb8C189413";
var theDAOStartingBlock = 1428757;
var theDAO = web3.eth.contract(theDAOABIFragment).at(theDAOAddress);
var theDAOCreatedTokenEvent = theDAO.CreatedToken({}, {fromBlock: theDAOStartingBlock, toBlock: theDAOStartingBlock + 200000});
console.log("address\tamount\tto\tblockHash\tblockNumber\tevent\tlogIndex\ttransactionHash\ttransactionIndex");
theDAOCreatedTokenEvent.watch(function(error, result){
  console.log(result.address + "\t" + result.args.amount / 1e16 + "\t" + result.args.to + "\t" +
    result.blockHash + "\t" + result.blockNumber + "\t" + result.event + "\t" + result.logIndex + "\t" +
    result.transactionHash + "\t" + result.transactionIndex);

});

EOF
```

Here's some sample data from the script above:

```
address                                    amount to                                         blockHash                                                          blockNumber event        logIndex transactionHash                                                    transactionIndex
0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413      3 0xb504e60998c6f354a0794abd91d85e8bc8436211 0x031d5bac6154ca7616ac62e966da2b50a0aaa1b3bc24958ed9cb52d8c8fc1e2f     1429038 CreatedToken        3 0xc96b0f95a1e7e8c07cd488a05f20f9e8d4003fe8eea0ec7f7f4bf199af3198e1                9
0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413     50 0x53024f875bc85709af41d1c65c01fb4cc92d5c1c 0x48cf967fc94c2f808d82906c1a56e3e09abc99bb8279266fbace13963dc30a1f     1429053 CreatedToken        0 0x1e9ec3974b89653961cbd996d4f6cfc2845db977a3385761b99ed459c2464740                1
0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413     50 0x2680a6fe5957d177a9279450d2c040818a1949a8 0x40d4235ceb2da6c0288016596d7b55223afd4efce70ba3369e915c0d8a5aa0b1     1429085 CreatedToken        0 0xcea9c261931268d55e695449794bc73a1d614b069051cdd437c1db3d2b31ae0a                0
```

### Script To Retrieve Transfer Events

```
#!/bin/sh

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Retrieve The DAO Transfer events. These events are from block 1599207 to 
# 1773290 and are continuing as transfers are still occurring.
#
# Usage:
#   1. Download this script to getTheDAOTransferEvents .
#   2. `chmod 700 getTheDAOTransferEvents`
#   3. Run `geth console` in a window.
#   4. Then run this script `./getTheDAOTransferEvents` in a separate window.
#
# Enjoy. (c) BokkyPooBah 2016. The MIT licence.
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

geth attach << EOF 
var theDAOABIFragment = [{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"CreatedToken","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"_amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"}];
var theDAOAddress = "0xBB9bc244D798123fDe783fCc1C72d3Bb8C189413";
var theDAOStartingBlock = 1599205;
var theDAO = web3.eth.contract(theDAOABIFragment).at(theDAOAddress);
var theDAOTransferEvent = theDAO.Transfer({}, {fromBlock: theDAOStartingBlock, toBlock: 'latest'});
console.log("address\tamount\t_from\t_to\tblockHash\tblockNumber\tevent\tlogIndex\ttransactionHash\ttransactionIndex");
theDAOTransferEvent.watch(function(error, result){
  console.log(result.address + "\t" + result.args._amount / 1e16 + "\t" + result.args._from + "\t" + 
    result.args._to + "\t" + result.blockHash + "\t" + result.blockNumber + "\t" + result.event + "\t" + 
    result.logIndex + "\t" + result.transactionHash + "\t" + result.transactionIndex);
});

EOF
```

Here's some sample data from the script above:

```
address                                     amount _from                                      _to                                        blockHash                                                          blockNumber event    logIndex transactionHash                                                    transactionIndex
0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413       5 0x198ef1ec325a96cc354c7266a038be8b5c558f67 0x428fbc00d1d36995f959f82690d9d16c66d643d2 0x26f05512b3a09ec8be28aa2a0810aa8fc725215d510f4836865c1e4ee0ef09e5     1599207 Transfer        0 0xe81c92ad910f44e6856f8db56a08d2ed771d2aeeed46844d3ba6fbdecffe9847                1
0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413 1000000 0x9cc04373e74f7dc7718d509025d12294656b328a 0x3507d25c89959890b598f7844e10a1ad482f3ffd 0x32aaafd1cabf518b3304a3333d9dd515a180e53606d6e98b2fe2c17c9c3e5342     1599208 Transfer        1 0x9137249f158563ed2829291552e7069a6e20d8fdd71d31e92c7c94c5fe05830b                1
0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413      20 0x8e3fc1ea5eeac9361b873355caa39f90c6b5ae06 0xfbb1b73c4f0bda4f67dca266ce6ef42f520fbb98 0x32aaafd1cabf518b3304a3333d9dd515a180e53606d6e98b2fe2c17c9c3e5342     1599208 Transfer        2 0x23d2fc74690bde686638d9c9f918340d39d3537912c0ed601cfb436789014c37                3
```