# Need help understanding Events

Tags: events

Here's an example from solidity [docs](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-events):

[SOLIDITY]

```
contract ClientReceipt {
    event Deposit(
        address indexed _from,
        bytes32 indexed _id,
        uint _value
    );

    function deposit(bytes32 _id) {
        Deposit(msg.sender, _id, msg.value);
    }
}
```

[JAVASCRIPT]

```
var ClientReceipt = web3.eth.contract(abi);
var clientReceipt = ClientReceipt.at(address);

var event = clientReceipt.Deposit();

event.watch(function(error, result){
    if (!error)
        console.log(result);
});
```

Now I'm getting a log every time somebody invokes a `deposit` function. It all works and I don't have any questions about that. What I can't understand is how an example from web3 api [docs](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-events) would work with the code above:

```
var event = myContractInstance.MyEvent({valueA: 23} [, additionalFilterObject])    
event.watch(function(error, result){
  if (!error)
    console.log(result);
});
```

**My questions:**

What does the property name `value1` represents? Is it the name of an indexed argument? What will I get in my console if I pass `{_value: 100}` as the first argument? Will I get in my console an event object only when someone triggers the event with the parameter named `_value` and the value **100**?

Comment: See http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4452/how-do-i-retrieve-the-voted-events-from-the-dao for some working examples of using filters with events.

Comment: @BokkyPooBah, that's exactly it! Thank you very much!!!