# What is the easiest way to view transaction history if a custom token?

Tags: history, etherscan

What do you think it's the easiest way to view history of transaction for a custom token ? Like A sent X to be B on XX/XX/XXXX. Especially for people who don't know about Ethereum.

A tool like etherscan falls into the "complicated" category (I don't even know how to recover data from it). Mist is decent, but can a bit tough to parse. Any app ? How hard is it to code one ?

Comment: If your custom token publishes events, you can retrieve the events as shown in http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4452/how-do-i-retrieve-the-voted-events-from-the-dao .

Comment: Thanks BokkyPooBah, they indeed send an event on transfer. I'm looking into it. But Basically, filtering this event in Mist should do it right ?Testing and self accepting answer if it works.

Comment: `How hard is it to code one?` Varies on the persons expertise no?