# How can I read log/events that have been triggered in the past?

Tags: web3js, events, logs, filters

I have a smart contract with an event.

```
    event NewContractCreated(address _callerAddress, address _newContractAddress);
```

I know how to actively listen for new events:

```
var newContractEvent = myContract.NewContractCreated();
newContractEvent.watch(function(error, result){
      if (!error){
        console.log("Success");
        console.log("New Contract Address: " + result.args._newContractAddress);
        console.log("Creator: " + result.args._callerAddress);
      }
  });
```

That works just fine for me. But my question is: how do I listen for and pull the exact same data for events that happened before I started watching?

I tried the exact same thing but using `get` instead of `watch`... it half worked. It printed the top line "Success" but did not print the rest of the log lines.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to specify the period (in block no) to watch. According the documentation [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethfilter)

> fromBlock: Number|String - The number of the earliest block (latest
>   may be given to mean the most recent and pending currently mining,
>   block). By default latest.
>
> toBlock: Number|String - The number of the latest block (latest may be
>   given to mean the most recent and pending currently mining, block). By
>   default latest.

In your case, that should work :

```
var newContractEvent = myContract.NewContractCreated();
newContractEvent.watch({fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'}, function(error, result){
      if (!error){
        console.log("Success");
        console.log("New Contract Address: " + result.args._newContractAddress);
        console.log("Creator: " + result.args._callerAddress);
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var newContractEvent = myContract.NewContractCreated({}, {fromBlock: 12345, toBlock: 'latest'});
newContractEvent.watch(function(error, result) {
    if (!error){
        console.log("Success");
        console.log("New Contract Address: " + result.args._newContractAddress);
        console.log("Creator: " + result.args._callerAddress);
        JSON.stringify(result);
    }
});
```

See [How do I retrieve the Voted events from The DAO](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4452/how-do-i-retrieve-the-voted-events-from-the-dao) for further information on using your event's indexed parameters as filter elements.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be

- Create a filter with options {fromBlock:.., toBlock:.., address:.Contract_addr.}
- Then use filter.get() to receive events from the past
- Consider caching of past events if you are using MetaMask or remote node