# web3: Do I need to `get` past events and `watch` future events separately?

Tags: web3js, events

As [discussed before](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11866/web3-how-do-i-get-past-events-of-mycontract-myevent) I managed to `get` past events via

```
myContract.myEvent({}, { fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest' }).get((error, results) => {
```

But it seems that for future events I need to `watch` for them via

```
myContract.myEvent().watch((error, result) => {
```

That is real odd in that I need to implement two event handlers - one for past and one for future events. Is there currently a cleaner way of handling this?

Comment: Which Ethereum node software are you using? When using Parity v1.5 I only need to make the first call you mention, and I get historical events and, later, new events.

Comment: I am using the latest released geth with the latest web3.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Semantically, past events are a finite list, while future events are an infinite list (i.e. stream). The latter can encompass the former, but not the other way around, i.e. you could represent all past and future events as a stream. This is not built in, but it wouldn’t be hard to implement if you really wanted to:

```
function allEvents(ev, cb) {   
  ev({}, { fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest' }).get((error, results) => {
    if(error) return cb(error)
    results.forEach(result => cb(null, result))
    ev().watch(cb)   
  }) 
}

...

allEvents(myContract.myEvent, (error, e) => {
  ...
})
```