# What does "Topics" mean in "Event log"?

Tags: events, etherscan, logs, terminology

When we invoke an event as follows :

```
event MyEvent(uint256 indexed _id, bytes32 _action, bytes32 _player, bytes32 _actionState,  address _owner);

emit MyEvent(uint256(_public_id), bytes32(_action), bytes32(_player), bytes32(_actionState), _owner);
```

In `EtherScan`, we see an output as follows :

[EtherScan Event Log](https://tobalaba.etherscan.com/tx/0xa59dc8835ddba82d0f7ea2596b5f2b0fcd4778d4cddb6631fb13d9a8346c8323#eventlog)

What does `Topics   [0] 0x22b8025a23f25c3f52cdbc1f53a831dbd4e3b4aaeebe121d36c858abea974bc7` mean ?

In case of `MyEvent`, `[1] 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001` means `_public_id = 1`

However, I do not know `0x22b8025a23f25c3f52cdbc1f53a831dbd4e3b4aaeebe121d36c858abea974bc7` comes from where ? and in general, the term of `Topics` what does it mean ?

Comment: @Ismael, Yeah u'r right, I did not see that question .... Sorry....

Comment: @Ismael However, I think the answer of user Lbrth_BoC is more related to what I expected. Thanks

Comment: @Ismael If you want to delete this question you can do it, but i think it would be better to keep answer of user Lbrth_BoC. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a transaction receipt the fied `topics` correspond to your event arguments which are `indexed` in your smart contract. For all events you will find as first argument the hash of the event name, and then the data which are `indexed` in hexabytes.

So in your case, in `topics` you will find

```
'topics':[hash_event_name,// w3.sha3(text='myEvent(uint256)').hex() where Event name without input argumentsname
         0x000000...000000001//your first argument '_id' because is indexed 
         ]
```

All of your event arguments which are not indexed are stored in the data part of the transaction receipt

Comment: Are you sure about this part? `sha('MyEvent(uint256'))`

Comment: With web3.py the correct thing is : `event_signature_hash = w3.sha3(text='MyEvent(uint256)').hex() #Event name without input arguments`

Comment: I'm trying to use [web3js 1.0](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#sha3) to get the sha of my event: `web3.utils.sha3('TokenSold(uint256 tokenId,uint256 oldPrice,uint256 newPrice,address prevOwner,address winner,string name)')` This gave me the wrong hash...

Comment: Yes because you input the name of your arguments inside the sha3 functions. So, you should get the correct hash with : `web3.utils.sha3('TokenSold(uint256, uint256, uint256, address, address, string)')`. Add only the type of your variable

Comment: Thanks so much! I got the correct hash with your solution but without the spaces! Cheers mate!!

Comment: you welcome ! I remember than I spent a couple of hours to get the correct hash too