# What is from address and Topic address in Remix log

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-debugging

I am invoking the buyTicket function of contract from account "0x14723A09ACff6D2A60DcdF7aA4AFf308FDDC160C"  in remix IDE  with 20 ethers which is clear from log but confused what is "from" and "topic" addresses  in Remix ide as per log below any idea please ?  Thanks

```
  event Deposit(address _from, uint _amount); 

 function buyTicket() public payable returns (bool success) { 
    if (numRegistrants >= quota) { return false; } // see footnote
     registrantsPaid[msg.sender] = msg.value;
     numRegistrants++;
     emit Deposit(msg.sender, msg.value);
     return true;
  }
```

***Remix Ide Log***

```
[
    {
        "*from*": "0x692a70d2e424a56d2c6c27aa97d1a86395877b3a",
        "***topic***": "0xe1fffcc4923d04b559f4d29a8bfc6cda04eb5b0d3c460751c2402c5c5cc9109c",
        "event": "Deposit",
        "args": {
            "0": "0x14723A09ACff6D2A60DcdF7aA4AFf308FDDC160C",
            "1": "20",
            "_from": "0x14723A09ACff6D2A60DcdF7aA4AFf308FDDC160C",
            "_amount": "20",
            "length": 2
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicates of this question ? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/49385/what-does-topics-mean-in-event-log/49389#49389

Answer (score 0):

`from`  should be the contract address.

`topics` is the hash name of your event in the smart contract

Comment: Sorry the addresses are not  the contrcat address the address are not in the list of  remix samples addresses.                                                                           I am talking about                    "*from*": "0x692a70d2e424a56d2c6c27aa97d1a86395877b3a" "***topic***": "0xe1fffcc4923d04b559f4d29a8bfc6cda04eb5b0d3c460751c2402c5c5cc9109c",
The address used in this contract 0x14723a09acff6d2a60dcdf7aa4aff308fddc160c buyer 
0x4b0897b0513fdc7c541b6d9d7e929c4e5364d2db  seller 
0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c  - contrcat

Comment: You right in this case, the `from`should be the address of the account who make the transaction/call the function

Comment: Sorry  Lbrth_BoC, please read my question above there are 2 from's (from and _from).  i know _from but 2nd "from" and "Topic" has unusual addresses which is unclear i am trying to find answer for both .

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the two `from`, I'm analysing that right now !

Comment: The `msg.sender` is always the account from who send the transaction/call the function. So obviously, the address loged as `_from` in your event should be exactly the same of the `from` above. (Here I understand why you ask:)). Please try to code this, just before your `if` statement in your smart contract  : `require(numRegistrant == msg.sender)` where `numRegistrant` should the account which call the function

Comment: and please if you can post all of your smart contract and don't forget to switch address in the drop down list of address in remix !

Answer (score 0):

You find those in the terminal window below the editor. Just click on the log to expand it and you will get all the details about the transaction

Comment: I meant what those address are pointing to ,  the address are no way related to Remix ..

Answer (score 0):

- **"from"**  is the address of the contract that emitted the event.

  **_"from "  and "_amount"**  are parameters which are defined in the signature of the event, in the code of the contract that emitted the
  event.