# Event Ordering in Ethereum

Tags: solidity, web3js, events

I am developing an application using solidity, web3js and [eventeum](https://github.com/eventeum/eventeum). I am testing it locally using ganache-cli. I use Kafka to store all the events to process them at convenience instead of processing them directly.

- The problem is that when I do truffle tests using my contract logic, the events are logged exactly in the order they were emitted.
- When eventeum captures them, the events do not appear in order in the kafka topic.
- When I listen to the same events simultaneously in separate web3js callback functions, they sometimes appear out of order.
- All these events are emitted within a single transaction.
- I am connected to the ganache from web3 and eventeum using `http://localhost:8545` as the endpoint for provider.

Is it normal that events from events to appear out of order within a single transaction?

P.S.

- Does connecting using `ws://` make a difference?
- Is it an anomaly with ganache-cli?

Comment: Possible suspect: I also read this post : https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/63745/can-we-assume-that-ethereum-events-aka-logs-are-in-sequence which says that for long chain of functions the order might get reversed. Any articles/posts on this as well.

Comment: @amabkaycee That out-of-orderedness is because the contracts themselves emit them in an undesired order but it should still be consistent.

Comment: In this case, I suspect the issue is asynchronous activities creating race conditions on the listener side. There is always a deterministic order on the blockchain side.