# How to find past contract events with web3py?

Tags: web3.py, python

It seems that web3js has a `getPastEvents()` method ([link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/102727/106115)) which returns all previous events for a given contract.

**Is there a similar feature in web3.py?**

I want to find all previous `Transfer` events of an ERC20 contract to keep a database of holders and their balance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`get_logs()`](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html?highlight=getlogs#web3.eth.Eth.get_logs) function does this.

For example:

```py
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=Web3.toChecksumAddress(CONTRACT_ADDRESS), abi=ABI)
events = contract.events.Transfer.getLogs(fromBlock=CONTRACT_CREATION_BLOCK)
```

Comment: How to do the same without initializing a contract instance? I would like to get all logs for a certain block in the past, and then parse/filter them. It seems that WS subscription is capable of receiving only the latest blocks/logs.