# Event and/or watch does not work

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation, contract-debugging, events, remix

I have a contract for a simple bidding scenario as below:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.9;

/* Contract accepting biddings during 30 minutes */
contract SimpleBidding {

    address contractOwnersAccount;
    uint deadline;

    struct Vendor {
        string name;
        address account;
        uint assetBarcode;
        uint stockCount;
    }

    //Vendor[] vendors;

    // request information
    address requester;
    uint requestedAssetBarcode;

    // bidding information
    uint expectedProposals;
    address bestVendor;
    uint bestPrice;

    //event VendorRegistered(string name, address account, uint assetBarcode, uint stockCount);
    event AssetRequested(address requester, uint barcode);
    event PriceProposed(address vendor, uint barcode, uint price);
    event BiddingFinished(uint barcode, uint price);
    event PaymentReceived(address sender, uint amount, uint barcode);
    event AssetShipped(uint barcode, uint trackingNumber);

    /* Constructor */
    function SimpleBidding() {
        // set the deadline of the contract as 10 minutes
        deadline = now + 30 * 1 minutes;
    }  

    /*
    function registerVendor(string name, uint assetBarcode, uint stockCount) {
        vendors[vendorsCount++] = Vendor(name, msg.sender, assetBarcode, stockCount);
        VendorRegistered(name, msg.sender, assetBarcode, stockCount);
    }*/

    /* Used by clients to request assets and start bidding.     */ 
    function requestAsset(uint barcode) {
        // save the requester
        requester = msg.sender;

        // save the asset barcode
        requestedAssetBarcode = barcode;

        // create the event
        AssetRequested(requester, requestedAssetBarcode);

        // initialize the bidding process
        expectedProposals = 2;
        bestPrice = 999999;
    }

    /* Used by vendors to propose a price for an asset. */
    function proposePrice(uint barcode, uint price) {
        // process the proposal
        PriceProposed(msg.sender, barcode, price);
        if (price < bestPrice) {
            bestPrice = price;
            bestVendor = msg.sender;
        }

        // update bidding condition
        expectedProposals--;

        if (expectedProposals == 0) {
            BiddingFinished(requestedAssetBarcode, bestPrice);
        }
    }

     /* The function without name is the default function that is called whenever 
       anyone sends funds to a contract */
    function () public payable {
        if (msg.sender == requester) {
            uint amount = msg.value;
            if (amount == bestPrice) {
                // transfer the payment to the vendor
                bestVendor.send(amount);
                // reduce the asset from the vendor's stock
                // ...to be implemented...

                // create the event
                PaymentReceived(msg.sender, msg.value, requestedAssetBarcode);

                // ship the asset
                uint trackingNumber = 23235235;
                AssetShipped(requestedAssetBarcode, trackingNumber);
            }

        }
    }

/*    function getVendor(uint id) constant returns (string name, address acc, uint barcode, uint numAssets) {
        var vendor = vendors[id];
        name = vendor.name;
        acc = vendor.account;
        barcode = vendor.assetBarcode;
        numAssets = vendor.stockCount;
    }*/

    modifier afterDeadline() { if (now >= deadline) _; }

    /* checks if the time limit has been reached and ends the contract */
    function dispose() afterDeadline {
        selfdestruct(contractOwnersAccount);
    }
}
```

And I deploy it as below:

```
loadScript("UnlockAccounts.js")
var simplebidding_sol_simplebiddingContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"barcode","type":"uint256"}],"name":"requestAsset","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"dispose","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"barcode","type":"uint256"},{"name":"price","type":"uint256"}],"name":"proposePrice","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"},{"payable":true,"type":"fallback"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"requester","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"barcode","type":"uint256"}],"name":"AssetRequested","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"vendor","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"barcode","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"price","type":"uint256"}],"name":"PriceProposed","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"barcode","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"price","type":"uint256"}],"name":"BiddingFinished","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"sender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"amount","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"barcode","type":"uint256"}],"name":"PaymentReceived","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"barcode","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"trackingNumber","type":"uint256"}],"name":"AssetShipped","type":"event"}]);
var simplebidding = simplebidding_sol_simplebiddingContract.new(
   {
     from: web3.eth.accounts[0], 
     data: '0x6060604052341561000c57fe5b5b61070842016001555b5b61030e806100266000396000f3006060604052361561003b5763ffffffff60e060020a6000350416632b25d4fd811461012b5780634c86659e14610140578063e161926914610152575b6101295b600254600090819033600160a060020a03908116911614156101235734915060065482141561012357600554604051600160a060020a039091169083156108fc029084906000818181858888f1505060035460408051600160a060020a033316815234602082015280820192909252517f5677b5d4cf976ac32defbd95a6a5aaf0d1fee450a11fc26f3c11aae6e6c33d0694509081900360600192509050a150600354604080519182526301628aa360208301819052815190927fb392290afa7f5b07c58b82f2a4f36a13e77050183671211ed5b5f27ca86b135e92908290030190a15b5b5b5050565b005b341561013357fe5b61012960043561016a565b005b341561014857fe5b6101296101eb565b005b341561015a57fe5b610129600435602435610206565b005b6002805473ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff191633600160a060020a0390811691909117918290556003839055604080519290911682526020820183905280517f182330bdae199ac3ad3e13c76eb719f687f880653f8dee040adc74327eaf3a669281900390910190a16002600455620f423f6006555b50565b600154421061020257600054600160a060020a0316ff5b5b5b565b60408051600160a060020a03331681526020810184905280820183905290517f753ea8d69d7d6b1f4d50c3fad4b7198d77bc061bcda3d58b777be0b28dc9b6189181900360600190a16006548110156102875760068190556005805473ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff191633600160a060020a03161790555b6004805460001901908190551515610123577fc17eabdf34dbdda04d4e5bc7f639984fff1d8a51ba4bb7f728e59744c3320e07600354600654604051808381526020018281526020019250505060405180910390a15b5b50505600a165627a7a72305820888b9c31e7518cdc3c92065dd42acf70adfa453a4456fce887ef823ea467b3c70029', 
     gas: '4700000'
   }, function (e, contract){
    console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
         console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
         simplebidding.AssetRequested().watch(function(error, result){
            if (error) {
               console.log(error);
               return;
            }
        console.log("[Asset " + result.args.barcode + " requested by " + result.args.requester + "]");
     }); 
    }
 })
```

Then I interact with it using `geth`.

```
> loadScript("contracts/SimpleBidding2.js")
null [object Object]
true
> null [object Object]
Contract mined! address: 0x11645eb08f8304f707fbc46f43abcc146a80c767 transactionHash: 0xdcc627ebd504f6d928f9e2916109e7404861deab1871011b200b58e20a4c7e98
> simplebidding.requestAsset.sendTransaction(1234, {from: eth.accounts[0]})
"0x2dc33bcee737ab1a821dc1c707db864aef9d645abe2143f2db817b90f59b3a92"
>
```

Normally, I would expect a log message here like `[Asset 1234 requested by 0x?????]`. However, I waited really long time and nothing happened. No error message or another thing to understand what is the problem. Any ideas? I am stuck here...

Comment: Nobody has no idea about this question?

Comment: You have to retrieve the events - see http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4452/how-do-i-retrieve-the-voted-events-from-the-dao for an example.

Comment: Start out by firing/reading events in a simple setting. Write a contract that only fires an event, write javascript code that only reads out this event. If you get that to work, try using it in a more complex scenario. I think it would be a lot easier to help you if you simplify your problem.

Comment: I finally found out that when I remove the line `requester = msg.sender;`, it works. No idea why it is like that. Any ideas?

Comment: I realized that `msg.sender` is undefined. However, I am calling it as:
`> simplebidding_sol_simplebidding.requestAsset.sendTransaction(9876, {from: eth.accounts[0]})
"0xd6fb82fc8ba155ad884c6ec5ebd1687c6425c3c3b731f6c8f3be3c506f9713bd"
> [Asset 9876 requested by undefined]`

Comment: try using a promise for your deployed object to make sure it is mined and created before your start watching it